# Extending almost disjoint family in a maximal set

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Call a family of sets $\mathcal{F} \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ *maximal* if there does not exist some $X \in [\omega]^\omega \setminus \mathcal{F}$ such that $X$ is almost disjoint with all elements of $\mathcal{F}$. Let $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be an almost disjoint family. Does there always exist some $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{A}' \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathcal{A}'$ is a mad (maximal almost disjoint) family?

I am also interested in the weaker question: Does every maximal family contain a mad family?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Here's how I expect the argument using Zorn's lemma would be: Let $\mathcal{A}' \supseteq \mathcal{A}$ be the maximal element in the poset you mentioned, and suppose for a contradiction that it is not a mad family. Then, some $X \notin \mathcal{A}'$ is almost disjoint from every element of $\mathcal{A}'$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is maximal, $X$ has infinite intersection with some element of $\mathcal{F}$. I don't see how we can derive a contradiction from there.

Comment: Sorry, misread.

Comment: I think there are trivial counterexamples to the question as stated. For example, if $\mathcal A$ is a mad family of subsets of the odds, then taking $\mathcal F = \{ X \cup 2\mathbb N :\, X \in \mathcal A\}$ is maximal, but clearly contains no mad family. Perhaps you want to ask whether $\mathcal F$ contains a *somewhere mad* family? Also, you'll want to insist $\mathcal F$ is infinite to avoid Joel's counterexample.

Comment: @WillBrian Even that version of the question admits a trivial counterexample by my answer.  (My $\mathcal{F}$ is infinite, if you use infinite $\mathcal{A}$.)

Comment: Clearly I have not thought through this question long enough. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every family $\mathcal{F}$ containing $\omega$ itself as a member is trivially maximal, since no infinite set is almost disjoint from $\omega$. But the family could otherwise consist of an almost disjoint non-maximal family $\mathcal{A}$. That is, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{A}\cup\{\omega\}$ is a counterexample.